# How does The DAO reimburse erroneous transactions to the sender?

Tags: exceptions, the-dao

Looking at the [account of The DAO in a blockchain explorer](https://etherscan.io/txs?a=0xbb9bc244d798123fde783fcc1c72d3bb8c189413&sort=value&order=desc), multiple transactions are marked as `Error occurred during contract Execution`. Most of the time this seems due to an `out of gas` exception, sometimes with quite some ether (like [this one](https://etherscan.io/tx/0x0ba83646d2fafee0b56a3d801b4f1dc5cd0eca693291d0fd024aab71abe298e7) with 15k ETH!) in the transaction. On the one hand [transactions which cause an exception still transfer the value to the recipient](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/Subtleties) but on the other the sender seems to be able to [re-send these Ether later](https://etherscan.io/address/0x94c742fd7a8b7906b3bfe4f8904fc0be5c768033). How can the DAO send those Ether back to the sender if the contract execution stopped due to an exception? Does the DAO re-imburse everything if it expects that there will be an `out of gas` exception and then `throw`s?

Comment: So it turns out that some subtleties have changed: when a transaction hits an exception, the Ether are reimbursed to the sender. The link in the question has not been updated.